# Fullcalendar - weekView with more content

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to show my weekly calendar on a screen without mouse or touch, so i need to put some more informations into the currently box.  Currently just showing  "Starttime" + "Title" .

But i need the field of "description"
I was trying to modify this part of code , but i wasn´t success:

```
    '<div class="fc-content">' +
    (timeText ?
        '<div class="fc-time"' +
            ' data-start="' + util_1.htmlEscape(startTimeText) + '"' +
            ' data-full="' + util_1.htmlEscape(fullTimeText) + '"' +
            '>' +
            '<span>' + util_1.htmlEscape(timeText) + '</span>' +
            '</div>' :
        '') +

    (eventDef.title ?
        '<div class="fc-title">' +
            util_1.htmlEscape(eventDef.title) +
            '</div>' :
        '') +

    '</div>' +
    '<div class="fc-bg"/>' +
```

(Line about 13833 fullcalendar.js)

For put in the information of color it´s easy:

```
          (eventDef.color ?
            '<div class="fc-title">' +
                util_1.htmlEscape(eventDef.color) +
                '</div>' :
            '') +
```

But i don´t know how to modify for put the field of description.

Comment: Why are you modifying fullCalendar.js just to do this? Use the eventRender callback provided in the API. It lets you modify the content of an event before it is shown in the calendar. Much easier than messing with the source code. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender (make sure you choose the docs which relate to your version of fullCalendar, there is a menu in the top right to do it)

Comment: thx, but  i am not very familiar in this field - i don´t know how to start , which file is the right one and so on. I thoughts its easy way just modify this but seems more complicated. .

Comment: There's no need to modify the source code of fullCalendar. Take a look at the documentation link I gave you. Try it. If you get stuck again with that then please update your question with your new code

Comment: dear, ... i don´t know. I bought this "Event Calendar - Php/Mysql Plugin" by envato [link]/https://codecanyon.net/item/event-calendar-phpmysql-plugin/19246267)  this contain the fullcalendar and with below  File structure [link](http://muvatec.de/calendar-files.jpg)   so my first problem to find the right file now

Comment: What do you mean find the right file? EventRender is something you add in **your** code when you set up the calendar

Comment: The [eventRender documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender) which I already linked to contains an example of how to use it. Somewhere in your page, maybe part of the plugin, maybe not, should be some code which looks a bit like that demo. That's where you need to write your eventRender code. I see from the codecanyon page that you are entitled to 6 months support from the author of the plugin, including help with 3rd party components (e.g. fullCalendar) - so maybe you should ask them specifically where you find that code within the plugin files.

Comment: yes, i already send them email for support! Thank you very much for your help